# ModuleNotFoundError when importing another package

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I'm trying to import a class from a script that is located in another package:

```
project_folder
 |
 | package_1
 |  | __init__.py
 |  |foo.py
 |  |
 | package_2
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | bar.py
```

In the script: "**bar.py**", I have the following import:

```
from package_1.foo import Class
```

This line generates the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_1'
```

Comment: What does `instance` refer to? How do you start your script (what command)?

Comment: I simplified the code, however forgot to change the module name. I have changed the description. I start my code by ``python bar.py``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the code from the package_2 directory then package_1 is not in your path so there is no knowledge of it to the interpreter.

From the project_folder directory you could run  `python -m package_2.bar` and then it will be in your path.

By path I mean the environment variable that is the list of directories the python interpreter looks for packages. By default it is some places relative to where you have python installed + the current directory. You could manually update this variable to be whatever you want (See https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path) but the most consistent way to run what you are describing is to run it from the directory above.